# how to get last value in a Stream<String> using rxdart?

Tags: dart, stream, flutter, rxdart

I have a stream that holds string values and i want to get the last value in that string. what's the best way to do it?

```
  Stream<String> get searchTextStream {
    return _searchController.stream.transform(
      StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (value, sink) {
          if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 4) {
            sink.addError('please enter some text..');
          } else {
            sink.add(value);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You are probably looking for a `BehaviourSubject`. https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html

Answer (score 21):

Get the rxDart package from here https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart.

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart'; // 1. Import rxDart package.
final _searchController = BehaviorSubject<String>();  // 2. Initiate _searchController as BehaviorSubject in stead of StreamController.

String _lastValue = _searchController.value; // 3. Get the last value in the Stream.
```

BehaviorSubject is an Object rxDart package.
It works like a StreamController, by default the broadcast() is on and BehaviorSubject has more function than StreamController.

Comment: If someone runs into the same issue: There seemed to be a breaking change in the rxdart package where you can not use .value directly on a BehaviorSubject anymore.
You would have to use "_searchController.valueWrapper.value"

Comment: this is wrong code. _searchController.value return Future<String> instead of a <String>

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart'; // 1. Import rxDart package.
final _searchController = BehaviorSubject<String>();  // 2. Initiate _searchController as BehaviorSubject in stead of StreamController.

String _lastValue;

_searchController.value.first.then((value){_lastValue = value; });
```

rxDart is uses asynchronous approach. so there is now synchronous way to get it. Method First makes a auto canceling subscription and execute callback function when value is ready.